# Get image height that is not in content

Tags: php, javascript, image, wordpress, height

I am building a custom wordpress theme and have a slideshow on the front page displaying images from blog posts.

Now if the image is over 300px in height I want to force its widthand center it vertically. So my question is:

Is there a way, in php or javascript to get the height of an image by only using the URL of the image?

EDIT: I tried this: `<?php list($height) = getimagesize(echo catch_that_image()); echo "<p>$height</p>"; ?>` where `catch_that_image()` returns the URL, but somehow this doesn't work (I think the first echo breaks it). Any ideas?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`image by only using the URL of the image?`

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
    alert('The size is ' + this.width + 'x' + this.height);
};
img.src = 'some image URL';
```

Try it
http://jsfiddle.net/NPSMN/

ps:

> I tried this: ... where
>   catch_that_image() returns the URL, but somehow this doesn't work (I
>   think the first echo breaks it). Any ideas?

did you look closer at your code? `echo` outputs to the browser, not to the argument of the function.

```
<?php 
list(,$height) = getimagesize(catch_that_image()); 
echo "<p>$height</p>"; 
?>
```

Comment: will try that. First time ever I am touching php :) EDIT: It works! thank you!

Comment: @SnippetSpace but the first element in returned array is the width. Try `list(,$height)` for the height

Answer (score 0):

See getimagesize() in PHP.  That will do what you're looking for.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php

```
<?php
    $url = "http://www.example.com/image.jpg";

    list($width, $height) = getimagesize($url);
    echo "Width: $width<br />Height: $height";
?>
```